# Exception during vector deallocation after using CudaMemcpy

Tags: c++, cuda

I have following function:

```
void Feed(const vector<double> &inputValues)
{
    vector<double> hOutputValues;
    vector<double> hOutputWeights;
    vector<double> hResultValues;

    double *dOutputValues;
    double *dOutputWeights;
    double *dResultValues;

    UpdateLayerOutputValues(_layers[0], inputValues);

    for (unsigned layernum = 1; layernum < _layers.size(); layernum++)
    {
        Layer &prevlayer = _layers[layernum - 1];       

        PrepareDeviceInputValues(prevlayer, hOutputValues, hOutputWeights); 
        hResultValues.resize(_layers[layernum].size() - 1);

        cudaMalloc(&dOutputValues, hOutputValues.size() * sizeof(double));
        cudaMemcpy(dOutputValues, &hOutputValues[0], hOutputValues.size() * sizeof(double),     cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        cudaMalloc(&dOutputWeights, hOutputWeights.size() * sizeof(double));
        cudaMemcpy(dOutputWeights, &hOutputWeights[0], hOutputWeights.size() * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        cudaMalloc(&dResultValues, hOutputWeights.size() * sizeof(double));     

        GetLayerOutputValues << <1, prevlayer.size() >> >(dOutputValues, dOutputWeights, dResultValues, _layers[layernum].size() - 1);

        cudaMemcpy(&hResultValues[0], dResultValues, hOutputWeights.size() * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);       

        UpdateLayerOutputValues(_layers[layernum], hResultValues);

        hResultValues.clear();      
    }

    hOutputValues.clear();
    hOutputWeights.clear();

    cudaFree(dOutputValues);
    cudaFree(dOutputWeights);
    cudaFree(dResultValues);
}
```

Function itself works fine but problem starts after I step out of it. I'm getting exception during deallocation of hResultValues vector. Problem does not exist if I comment out line:

> cudaMemcpy(&hResultValues[0], dResultValues, hOutputWeights.size() * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

At first I thought that maybe there is something wrong with vectors and I tried to replace hResultValues with an array but I still get an exception.

I do not get any exception message but what i found is that int _CrtIsValidHeapPointer() method in dbgheap.c throws that exception.

Can anyone explain to me what is the cause of my problem?

Comment: The behavior is undefined if the vector is empty and you use `&vector[0]`.  But in general, why doesn't your code do any error checking whatsoever?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this vector should never be empty. vector::resize(size) is based on other object that for sure is never empty. Anyway as I said this function works as I expect (even if this probably isn't most efficient code). Problems start when I step out of this function and vector cleaning starts.

Comment: Well, I'm saying that accessing [0] on an empty vector is undefined behavior.  If you want to leave that hole in your program, then you've been warned.

Comment: As to error checking, did you check if `hResultValues.size() >= dResultValues`?  You're copying over those values to a vector that was not sized using `dResultValues`.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `hResultValues.size() >= hOutputWeights.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @PaulMcKenzie i figured out what was wrong with my code. Basically hResultValues was size of _layers[layernum].size() - 1 but lines:

- cudaMalloc(&dResultValues, hOutputWeights.size() * sizeof(double));
- cudaMemcpy(&hResultValues[0], dResultValues, hOutputWeights.size() * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

had incorrect size. That error was caused by my changes to the code. Before and Paul figure out hResultValues was of the size of hOutputWeights but later I decided to make some more calculations on GPU and as a result finad hResultValues was smaller than hOutputWeights. While I was making necessary changes I correctly changed size of hResultValues but forgot to change size of allocated memory.

Correct solution to this problem is:

```
cudaMalloc(&dResultValues, (layernum].size() - 1) * sizeof(double));
cudaMemcpy(&hResultValues[0], dResultValues, (layernum].size() - 1) * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```